# Pointer loses information when passing into function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

edit, I'll try to give a better exemple:

first I'll tell your about the program:
basicly, there' two phases, the first is inserting the words (works perfectly fine)

```
struct trieLeaf {
    keyType age = 1;
};
class Trie 
{
private:
    dataType character;
    trieLeaf *leaf = nullptr;
    class Trie **alphabet = nullptr;


int main()
{
    string input;
    Trie dictionary('\0');
    while (getline(cin, input) && input[0] != '.')
    {
            dictionary.analyzeText(input);
    }
    while (getline(cin, input) && input[0] != '.')
    {
        dictionary.approxFind(input);
    }
    system("pause>null");
}
```

second phase is searching for words, if words is found then I need to reduce the number of times it has been added by 1.
if number of times it has been added is 0, then I remove it.

```
    void Trie::approxFind(string &word)
{
    int index = 0;
    string result;
    Trie *curr;
    if (curr=find(word))
    {
        cout << curr->leaf->age << endl;
        curr->leaf->age -= 1;
        if (curr->leaf->age == 0)
        {
            remove(word);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result = approximate(word);
        cout << "Did you mean " << result << "?\n";
    }
}
Trie* Trie::find(const string &word)
{
    int index = 0;
    Trie *curr = this;
    while (word[index] != '\0')
    {
        if (curr->alphabet[word[index] - 'a'] != nullptr)
        {
            curr = curr->alphabet[word[index++] - 'a'];
        }
        else
        {
            return (nullptr);
        }
    }
    if (curr->leaf != nullptr)
    {
        return (curr);
    }
}
void Trie::remove(const string &word)
{
    int index = 0;
    Trie *curr = this, **tempArr, *temp;
    while (word[index] != '\0')
    {
        tempArr = curr->alphabet;
        temp = curr;
        curr = curr->alphabet[word[++index] - 'a'];
        if (!isArrEmpty(tempArr))
        {
            delete(tempArr);
        }
        delete(temp);
        temp = nullptr;
    }
}
bool Trie::isArrEmpty(Trie **alphabet)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < 26; index++)
    {
        if (!alphabet[index])
        {
            return (true);
        }
    }
    return(false);
}
```

TempArr in isArrEmpty is losing the object it's pointing to when passing onto the funcion.
I hope it gives a better idea why

Comment: Undefined behavior someplace. Can't tell you where. A [mcve] is a required to tell you exactly what\s wrong.

Comment: My simple hint for you would be to think about why main takes 2 arguments `char** argv` and `int argc`. Long name for these two should be something like `argument values` and `argument count`.

Comment: Why are you deleting temp? Temp is equal to this in the first while iteration, so you delete the object and then continue the function in it. I'm pretty sure that's the undefined behavior @StoryTeller is telling you about

Comment: What is this supposed to do? `if (!alphabet+index)`

Comment: Temp is being deleted after I call the function so it's no about that.
@StoryTeller how can I give a better explantion? the whole code is about 300 lines...

Comment: The link I provided tells you about how to craft such an example. And it contains other useful links on that page too. You may find yourself solving the problem on your own along the way.

Comment: Since every node has 26 pointer, you should have an array of 26 pointers, not a pointer that you need to allocate each time.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews you're right, but I already did and I rather finish it my way.

Comment: Um i've added the rest of the function I use in the proccess, I hope it's better.

Comment: debugger shows 'struct at NULL', is it helpful?

Comment: class Trie incomplete.